# Can grpc and express server run by same nodejs server, or grpc has to be different server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, grpc, grpc-node

I am trying to create a REST server which will be based on Node/Express. How to add a GRPC server in the same REST server, or it has to be completely different NodeJS server which will host only the GRPC server.

Comment: There is a blogpost+repo by Diego Garcia, that says that it is possible. However it uses the Go language https://medium.com/@drgarcia1986/listen-grpc-and-http-requests-on-the-same-port-263c40cb45ff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add a gRPC server to an Express server. You can run a gRPC server in the same process as an Express server, but they will serve on separate ports and run independently.

Comment: I tried this approach, I think that's the way to go.

Comment: @Asutosh would you mind adding your own answer or expand this one to show how you actually did it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did which is basically triggering the GRPC server start on the `listen` callback of express

```
import express from "express";

import { Server,  ServerCredentials } from "grpc";

const server = new Server();
server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', ServerCredentials.createInsecure());

const router = express.Router();

express()
  .use("/", router)
  .listen(3000, () => {
    server.start();
    console.log("listening");
  });
```